# Is there a way to add Unix commands to GitKraken?

Tags: windows, unix, command-line, gitkraken

**How can I use unix commands in Gitkraken?**

So I've recently picked up coding again, going back to the basics, and when I was learning previously I used windows and installed Git Bash which uses a Unix command-line environment if I'm not mistaken. The Odin Project (the website I am learning to code from) does not support Windows as an operating system when learning to code due to various reasons listed on their website. I believe that Windows is adequate and would like to continue using it instead of using VMware or VirtualBox to 'install' Linux. The only issue I'm having is executing commands using GitKraken. Some of the commands are different, so I was just wondering if there is a way to use Unix commands in GitKraken? At this point, I am just curious if it is possible. I can continue to use Git Bash, however, GitKraken displaying a visual map of my repos is very helpful.

Ex. How to open a file

$ open ./index.html  - macOS

$ start index.html - Windows OS

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess yes, but maybe no. Sorry, but what is your actual goal? And what are the problems you encounter? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, be clear about what you want to achieve. Just for the record, yes, you can develop on Windows, it's not like it's a some obscure platform. Things may be different though, but those can be addressed on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question is how can I use Unix commands in GitKraken? I would like it to operate similar to Git Bash where it operates as a Unix command-line environment.

Comment: Git Bash in Windows is a replacement for the combination of the normal `bash` and `git` in Linux. Simply use a normal terminal window to get a `bash` and use the same `git` commands as you do in Git Bash on Windows. (Assuming `bash` is your login shell.) GitKraken is a commercial graphical client with a free version.